# I can't figure why am i getting a segment fault in this dynamic stack

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I'm trying to make a board 5x5 and in the middle of this board (that's mean i > 0 and  i < 4 ) i want to put a piece in this sub board in randomic way, only 7 theme(if the random number are the same than previous the print have to be the sum of all the pieces above each others).I'm using the dynamic stack for training purpose. I can drew the board exact like i want but i couldn't solve till now de segmentation fault
(**EDIT**: I already responded this questions with details.)
here is all code;

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct peca
{
  int andares;
  int parque;
  int teto;
  struct peca *prox;
} peca;

typedef struct jogador
{
  int andares;
  int parque;
  int teto;
} jogador;


int aleatorio[101];
main ()
{
  jogador norte, sul, leste, oeste;
  peca *tabuleiro[5][5];
  int por_parque = 0;
  
  srand(time(NULL));
  for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
  {
    aleatorio[i] =  rand() % 4;
    if(i % 2 == 0  && i == 0)
    {
      aleatorio[i] = aleatorio[i] + 2;
    }
    else if (i % 2 != 0  && i == 0)
    {
      aleatorio[i]++;
    }
    
  }
  
  printf ("         ");
  printf ("          Norte\n");


  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
    
      printf ("         ");
      printf ("+");
      for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
      {
        printf ("----");
        if (j % 5 == 0);
        {
          printf ("+");
        }
        }
     
      printf ("\n");
      if (i == 2)
      {
        printf ("  Oeste  ");
        printf ("|");
      }
      else
      {
        printf ("         ");
        printf ("|");
      }
      
      for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
      {
        if ((k > 0 && k < 4) && (i > 0 && i < 4))
        {
          bool vazio_ou_n = false;
          //===========================================================================================
          for (int l = 0; l < 100; l++)
          {
            if (aleatorio[l] == k && aleatorio[l + 1] == i)
            {
              por_parque++;
              vazio_ou_n = true;
              break;
            }
            
          }
          if (vazio_ou_n && por_parque < 7)
          {
            //============================================================================================
            peca * n = malloc(sizeof(peca));
            if (n == NULL)
            {
              printf("erro");
              return 1;
            }
            n->andares++;
            if(tabuleiro[i][k] == NULL)
            {
              tabuleiro[i][k] = n;
              n->prox = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
              n -> andares = tabuleiro[i][k] -> andares;
              n -> andares++;
              n -> prox = tabuleiro[i][k];
              tabuleiro[i][k] = n;

            }
            
            
            printf("  %d ", tabuleiro[i][k]->andares);
            printf ("|");
            vazio_ou_n = false;
            continue;
          }
          else if (vazio_ou_n && por_parque == 7)
          {
            //=====================================================================

            peca * n = malloc(sizeof(peca));
            n->parque = 1; 
            if (tabuleiro[i][k] == NULL)
            {
              tabuleiro[i][k] = n;
            }
            else
            {
              por_parque--;
              continue;
            }
            
            

            printf("[ %d]", tabuleiro[i][k]->parque);
            printf ("|");
            vazio_ou_n = false;
            continue;
          }
          
        }
        
        for (int l = 0; l < 4; l++)
        {
          printf ("%c", ' ');   //"liga" o desenho do tabuleiro a matriz do jogo
        }
        if (k % 5 == 0);
        {
          printf ("|");
        }
        }
      //letras do lado direito do tabuleiro
      printf (" %c", i + 97);
      if (i == 2)
      {
        printf ("  Leste  ");
      }
      printf ("\n");
    }
  // ultima linh do tabuleiro
  printf ("         ");
  printf ("+");
  for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
      printf ("----");
      if (j % 5 == 0);
      {
    printf ("+");
      }
    }
  //numeros de baixo do tabuleiro
  printf ("\n");
  printf ("           ");
  for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
      printf (" %d  ", j + 1);
      if (j % 5 == 0);
      {
    printf (" ");
      }
    }
  printf ("\n");
  printf ("         ");
  printf ("          Sul\n");

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
      peca* tmp = NULL;
      peca* fre = tabuleiro[i][j];
      while (fre != NULL)
      {
        tmp = fre -> prox;
        free(fre);
        fre = tmp;
      }
      
    }
    
  }
  
}
```

the part that that i have been thinking tha were the bug

````
            if (n == NULL)
            {
              printf("erro");
              return 1;
            }
            n->andares++;
            if(tabuleiro[i][k] == NULL)
            {
              tabuleiro[i][k] = n;
              n->prox = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
              n -> andares = tabuleiro[i][k] -> andares;
              n -> andares++;
              n -> prox = tabuleiro[i][k];
              tabuleiro[i][k] = n;

            } ```


I'm new programing and i still don't know use debugger very well, so if anyone can help, i'm glad
````

Comment: `peca *tabuleiro[5][5];` should be `peca tabuleiro[5][5];`

Comment: Crank up the warning messages and resolve them. If you still have errors after that, update the question with the new code and ask again. I'm getting 13 warnings, but I've got my compiler set to anally retentive. Also consider removing the C++ tag. No self-respecting C++ compiler will accept this code.

Comment: `peca *tabuleiro[5][5];` declares 25 *Uninitialized Pointers*. You cannot check `if(tabuleiro[i][k] == NULL)`. If you want to initialize the pointers `NULL`, then do so with `peca *tabuleiro[5][5] = {{NULL}};` (there are likely many other errors as well, but this looks to be the immediate SegFault)

Comment: May you type it as a answer to i can do set up to right one please?@DavidC.Rankin

Answer (score 0):

(i%2==0 && i==0)
You're telling the computer: if it's even and is equal to zero.. . See it?

Answer (score 0):

It was a poor code but I believe now it might help someone. Besides the other errors , I'll show them in the code below. The main problem was the segment fault and the way I was dealing with pointers. And it is the main point that I would like to talk about, because this is what will help whoever find this question and also is the answer to this question.

There are two errors exactly regarding the poiterns dealing. The first one is `peca *tabuleiro[5][5];` where is the segment fault. In some "intuitive way" while you are coding you may think the  once you typed `peca *tabuleiro[5][5];` as `int` type variables, this will be set to `NULL` automatically as a pattern behavior.

But it points to a random location in memory when you declare it. It could be pointing into the system stack, or the global variables, or into the program's code space, or into the operating system. It should be `peca *tabuleiro[5][5] = {{NULL}};` becouse you **need** to set them for `NULL`.

And the second error was that for the almost same reason, once you fix the mistake there are some random huge integers instead of what is expected. And this is happening because once was created the new peace `peca * n = malloc(sizeof(peca));` the `n->andares` point to a space in memory but not overlay the integer there. I fix the code and commented what i replace.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
/*#include<stdlib.h>*/
#include<time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct peca
{
  int andares;
  int parque;
  int teto;
  struct peca *prox;
} peca;

typedef struct jogador
{
  int andares;
  int parque;
  int teto;
} jogador;


int aleatorio[101];
int main ()
{
  jogador norte, sul, leste, oeste;
  /*peca *tabuleiro[5][5];*/
  peca *tabuleiro[5][5] = {{NULL}};
  int por_parque = 0;
  
  srand(time(NULL));
  for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
  {
    aleatorio[i] =  rand() % 4;
    /*if(i % 2 == 0  && i == 0)*/
    if(i % 2 == 0  || i == 0) 
    {
      aleatorio[i] = aleatorio[i] + 2;
    }
    /*else if (i % 2 != 0  && i == 0)*/
    else if (i % 2 != 0  ||  i == 0)
    {
      aleatorio[i]++;
    }
    
  }
  
  printf ("         ");
  printf ("          Norte\n");


  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
    
      printf ("         ");
      printf ("+");
      for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
      {
        printf ("----");
        if (j % 5 == 0);
        {
          printf ("+");
        }
        }
     
      printf ("\n");
      if (i == 2)
      {
        printf ("  Oeste  ");
        printf ("|");
      }
      else
      {
        printf ("         ");
        printf ("|");
      }
      
      for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
      {
        if ((k > 0 && k < 4) && (i > 0 && i < 4))
        {
          bool vazio_ou_n = false;
          //===========================================================================================
          /*for (int l = 0; l < 100; l++)*/
          for (int l = 0; l < 99; l++)
          {
            if (aleatorio[l] == k && aleatorio[l + 1] == i)
            {
              por_parque++;
              vazio_ou_n = true;
              break;
            }
            
          }
          if (vazio_ou_n && por_parque < 7)
          {
            //============================================================================================
            peca * n = malloc(sizeof(peca));
            

            if (n == NULL)
            {
              printf("erro");
              return 1;
            }

            n->andares = 1;
            n->teto = 0;
            n->parque = 0;
            n->prox = NULL;
            /*n->andares++;*/
            if(tabuleiro[i][k] == NULL)
            {
              tabuleiro[i][k] = n;
              n->prox = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
              n -> andares = tabuleiro[i][k] -> andares;
              n -> andares++;
              n -> prox = tabuleiro[i][k];
              tabuleiro[i][k] = n;

            }
            
            
            printf("  %d ", tabuleiro[i][k]->andares);
            printf ("|");
            vazio_ou_n = false;
            continue;
          }
          else if (vazio_ou_n && por_parque == 7)
          {
            //=====================================================================

            peca * n = malloc(sizeof(peca));
            n->parque = 1; 
            if (tabuleiro[i][k] == NULL)
            {
              tabuleiro[i][k] = n;
            }
            else
            {
              por_parque--;
              continue;
            }
            
            

            printf("[ %d]", tabuleiro[i][k]->parque);
            printf ("|");
            vazio_ou_n = false;
            continue;
          }
          
        }
        
        for (int l = 0; l < 4; l++)
        {
          printf ("%c", ' ');   //"liga" o desenho do tabuleiro a matriz do jogo
        }
        if (k % 5 == 0);
        {
          printf ("|");
        }
        }
      //letras do lado direito do tabuleiro
      printf (" %c", i + 97);
      if (i == 2)
      {
        printf ("  Leste  ");
      }
      printf ("\n");
    }
  // ultima linh do tabuleiro
  printf ("         ");
  printf ("+");
  for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
      printf ("----");
      if (j % 5 == 0);
      {
    printf ("+");
      }
    }
  //numeros de baixo do tabuleiro
  printf ("\n");
  printf ("           ");
  for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
      printf (" %d  ", j + 1);
      if (j % 5 == 0);
      {
    printf (" ");
      }
    }
  printf ("\n");
  printf ("         ");
  printf ("          Sul\n");

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
      peca* tmp = NULL;
      peca* fre = tabuleiro[i][j];
      while (fre != NULL)
      {
        tmp = fre -> prox;
        free(fre);
        fre = tmp;
      }
      
    }
    
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I redone this  [project](https://github.com/igor439/Skyliners) and proposed a mathematical way to solve the proposed main problem. Hope that it was helpfull.

Comment: Limit the paragraph to no more than 2 or 3 sentences. Divide your answer into clear points as much as you can. It will be difficult to understand the whole answer in a one go